# why is DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping deprecated?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, class DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated. Documentation ( http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html ) says:

> Deprecated. 
>   in Spring 3.2 in favor of RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Why is it deprecated? What practical problems of this class were fixed in RequestMappingHandlerMapping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Framework is an open-source project hosted on GitHub so all this information is easy to find in the code:

1. Find the source file in question: [click](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java)
2. Switch to "blame" view: [click](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/v3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java)
3. Find all occurences of "`@Deprecated`" to find the associated commit: [click](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/77223d7ced49fffd4b9654d5045c5bba0865ef7c)
4. Commit message mentions "SPR-10005", find it in Spring JIRA: [click](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10005) (2023 note: Spring migrated to Github issues at some point, [direct link here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14639))
5. The JIRA ticket contains a link to the "what's new in version 3.1.3" document: [click](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-in-3.1-handler-method-controller-processing)

The relevant part:

> The new classes were developed in response to many requests to make annotation controller support classes more customizable and open for extension. Whereas previously you could configure a custom annotated controller method argument resolver, with the new support classes you can customize the processing for any supported method argument or return value type.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer, I learn much more for I expected.