# How to access getHandlerMap() via RequestMappingHandlerMapping after DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping was deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Since [Spring has deprecated `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490213/why-is-defaultannotationhandlermapping-deprecated) and has been replaced by `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, I'm stuck with a case where I had code like below:

```
@Autowired
private DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

//in an API that lists handler mapping
Map<String, Object> handlerMap = handlerMapping.getHandlerMap();
```

Now, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` doesn't provide this method. Which function can I use to get the desired handler map?

**Things to consider while answering:**

- I have limited knowledge about how handler mapping works basically limited to what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740958/how-defaultannotationhandlermapping-works).

**Things I have been looking at:**

- I tried to go through the parent classes for both `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` & `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. I reached the conclusion that `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` is the function that contains `getHandlerMap()` and extends `AbstractHandlerMapping`.
- `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` has `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping<T>` as a super parent and extends `AbstractHandlerMapping` but I couldn't find something similar to `getHandlerMap()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out since `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` is the class that holds the function and getHandlerMap going by it's javadoc

> Return the registered handlers as an unmodifiable Map, with the registered path as key and the handler object (or handler bean name in case of a lazy-init handler) as value.

Since this is an internal Spring map any class that extends `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` can be used to retrieve the map. Specifically, I used `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`.

Comment: This will give you an empty map. It contains only the mappings for the given `HandlerMapping` not all the URLs.

Comment: @M.Deinum I couldn't understand what you mean by given `HandlerMapping`. I don't pass a handler mapping anywhere, do you mean spring internally uses the class(e.g. `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`) to populate the handler map? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: You answered your question by stating you used `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`. If you inject a `HandlerMapping` you will only be able to retrieve the mappings internal to that `HandlerMapping` not all available mappings. The `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` will NOT contain the mappings detected by the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`...

Comment: Alright, but then how do I access the mappings for `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`? Since it doesn't provide the `getHandlerMap()` function.

Comment: The quick answer, you don't as the mappings are internal to that class instance. The long answer you could use reflection to pull out the mappings.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you point me to a link doing something similar to the long answer you mentioned above?

Comment: There is no real answer, it was mere a figure of speech.